# At run-time, how can you adjust the dimensions of the UIPickerView UI window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

During run-time, how can you adjust the dimensions of the UIPickerView UI window?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIPickerView's height and width are unchangeable in iOS. This is mostly due to Apple's human interface guidelines guaranteeing consistency from the user's standpoint.

All you can do is change it's position on the screen.

The only way to create a UIPickerView with different dimensions would be to write your own Picker from scratch.